# How can I apply preventDefault() to the click on CodeMirror-hints?

Tags: wp-editor

If I click on a selection in the autocompleter of WordPress in codeMirror, the whole field is closed. To prevent this I want to add preventDefault to the click event.

```
var cm = wp.codeEditor.initialize( options.field, editorSettings );
var editor = cm.codemirror;

jQuery('body').hover(function(e){
          if(jQuery('ul.CodeMirror-hints')){
            jQuery('ul.CodeMirror-hints').mousedown(function(eH){
              eH.preventDefault();
            });
          }
        });

var editorSettings = {
        mode: 'css',
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 2,
        tabSize: 2,
        autoRefresh:true,
        autocorrect: true,
        autocapitalize: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        lineWrapping: true,
        lint: true,
        gutters: [ 'CodeMirror-lint-markers' ]
    }
```

Since ul.CodeMirror-hints is now stored in the body element and is only inserted when codeMirror hints makes a suggestion, I have to make an event on body.

```
body => <ul class="CodeMirror-hints"...</ul>
```

Is there a better solution to add preventFefault() to the event click on ul.CodeMirror-hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event delegation is your friend!  This way the element doesn't have to exist when the code runs to have the function bound to it.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'ul.CodeMirror-hints li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

replace `click` with `mousedown` if you need to

Comment: Runs super and saves a lot of insecure code

Comment: jQuery event delegation is super slick and easy.  You could make it a little more performant if you found the closest parent element that always exists and bound the click event to that instead of body.  Doesn't make that much of a difference though

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not beautiful but it does what it should.

```
jQuery('body').hover(function(e){
          if( jQuery('ul.CodeMirror-hints li').length > 0){
            jQuery('ul.CodeMirror-hints li').mousedown(function(eH){
              eH.preventDefault();
            });
            jQuery('ul.CodeMirror-hints li').click(function(ecH){
              ecH.preventDefault();
            });
          }
```